# Scroll problems with empty PS1

Tags: bash, scroll, ps1

If I scroll up through the history and come across a long line that wraps, then scroll back down, the lines will be scrambled.

I have read around that this can be caused by incorrectly escaping color codes, but this happens even with an empty PS1, e.g.

```
export PS1=""
```

In response to comment

```
echo "[$PROMPT_COMMAND]"
[]
echo "[$PS1]"
[]
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Linux. Do you have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set? Also, do `echo "[$PS1]"` to make sure it's empty (you should get `[]`).

Comment: Which terminal are you using, and what's the `$TERM` setting?

Comment: @svnpenn when the *lines are scrambled*, type `echo $COLUMNS`, then confirm that the number given is the width in characters of the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `Ctrl+L` to refresh the display.

I think the problem is more with **Bash** not knowing long commands are broken into multiple lines.